# To which extent is the treatment of nuclear multipole radiation by the means of a classical electromagnetic field valid?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

In the treatment of nuclear multipole radiation, for example in the context of nuclear gamma decay, it is standard, at least at the elementary level, to formalize the electromagnetic radiation as a classical field, by decomposing it in its multipole components, and to use non-relativistic quantum mechanics to deduce the rates of emission/absorption of radiation. To which extent is this treatment valid and when does this approximation break down? Apart from the various g-factor anomalies and radiative corrections to the electric charge, are the predictions of quantum field theory in good agreement with those provided by the semi-quantum, non-relativistic approximation?

Comment: I don't think the decomposition of the electromagnetic field into different multiples requires a classical treatment. In fact, gamma decay can be thought of in terms of the emission of e.g. a quadrupole photon, which is a quantum mechanical concept.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: Sure. When quantizing the EM field, one expands it into modes. Typically, this is done in plane waves, and each plane wave is quantized. But you can also expand in multipoles and quantize those. The validity of the non-relativistic approximation is related to the validity of that approximation for nuclear structure, which is pretty good.

Comment: Ok, so you basically say that while I've been using a classical EM field, I could have used EM field operators in the appropriate formalism and I would have gotten essentially the same results? Are you saying this as a matter of principle, or do you have actual experience with such calculations? (As for the validity of the non relativistic approximation, I gave it a bit of analysis myself, so I am convinced with that).

Comment: It may help you to take a look at chapter 5 of Samuel Wong's text book.